# Automated script that changed LTR to RTL

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to try an automated script that will change LTR Wordpress themes to RTL Wordpress theme. Basically, I want to change "left" to "right" and "right" to "left" in the theme's style.css file; I've tried to do **str_replace()** the word "left" to "right" and the opposite, but after it changes "left" to "right", it changes it back to "left" after I execute the second str_replace().

Any ideas?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, including: "matching both cases in a single regular expression" and "first replacing 'left' with something else and then later changing that to 'right'". But do you really think you have a good chance at generating a RTL theme like that?

Comment: Thanks, Frank. I believe it worths the try, and at least let it do the basic for me and I'll fix it from there.

Comment: How about if you do `if ( stripos( 'left', $style_css ) !== false ) { ... replace "left" here } else { ... replace "right" here }` . This way you will only execute one replace and not both :)

Answer (score 1):

As I am working with Bilingual wordpress I can suggest you to use qTranslate plugin.

And then you can switch themes with following:

```
        <?php if (qtrans_getLanguage() == 'ar'): #use your own language name here. ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/style_rtl.css"; ?>" />
        <?php else: ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
```